# Firebase phone authorization - sms wrong format

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I found a very strange problem. I use Firebase authorization with the phone number.

When I call `signInWithPhoneNumber` Firebase sends me sms with format like:

9 1.1. 02.3

On the second call sends a normal sms with format like:

911023

Any ideas?

Comment: everytime or does it happen once?

Comment: Hm... today. This happens when remove user from firebase auth and create again =(

Comment: that's so odd, there's no such bug reported so far.